# Remote Jupyter kernel (over ssh) crashes when X11 connection is closed

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter, x11-forwarding, jupyter-kernel

#### My python analysis setup:

I run long sessions of a Python3 console on a ssh server. I keep them running inside tmux across multiple connections.
I either run IPython3, or more recently I launch a `jupyter kernel` that I connect to a console using `jupyter console --existing kernel-358b-xxxxxx.json`.

I need to use matplotlib to draw graphs, but this requires a connection to a forwarded X11. Therefore, I use `ssh -XY`, and ensure that the `DISPLAY` variable is set correctly before running the kernel/console.
I then plot things interactively using the `%matplotlib` magic, which uses the "TkAgg" backend.

#### Ssh disconnect and reconnect loses the X11 server and crashes python

First, when disconnecting from the server (Ctrl-D), the connection does not close until I hit Ctrl-C. I suspect this is killing the X11 connection initiated by Python.
The jupyter kernel then throws the following error:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "localhost:11.0"
      after 8432 requests (8432 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

and usually I need to restart the kernel entirely, losing all variables.
This is a major hurdle in my workflow. I have tried running the pyplot command `plt.switch_backend("Agg")` to stop using X11 before disconnecting, but it does not help.

#### Question

*How to disconnect a jupyter kernel from X11 to avoid crashes between ssh sessions?*
Maybe a jupyter kernel code could be executed via `jupyter-run`?

Note that it is not possible to allow a local jupyter console to connect to the remote kernel because of network limitations on my work server (currently basic ssh-ing works, but not port forwarding).

Comment: Run `jupyter notebook` inside a `tmux` or `screen` session?

Comment: I do run a kernel inside tmux. However I am not interested in jupyter notebook (matter of taste, I prefer scripts + console setup). Also current network limitations block access to jupyter notebooks...